# access "about:blank" page from Google Slide Presenter in custom Chrome extension (using content_scripts)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

In my manifest.json that loads a css I tried using

```
"content_scripts":[{
     "matches": ["about:blank*"],
        "css": ["main.css"]
    }]
```

But it doesn't trigger, I also tried "https://docs.google.com/*" and even "<all_urls>".

Is this an internal page that Google Slide opens and thus need a different approach?

FYI - To open Presenter view in a new tab on mac you must first put the browser into full screen mode and then start presenter view, that way the presenter view opens in a new tab as "about:blank" and dev tools open.

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I found out about ["match_about_blank" flag](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/) set to true allows access to about pages, but it still needs matches set to the domain, which results in applying the css to all pages of that domain as opposed to only the about page opened by presenter view from docs.google.com.

```
"content_scripts":[{
 "matches": ["https://docs.google.com/*"],
  "match_about_blank" : true,
  "css": ["main.css"]
 }]
```

**Can I target somehow only that about page specifically from that domain or perhaps use javascript to only apply it when a given div is present?**

The main div displayed is "punch-viewer-speakernotes" in the presenter view.

I want to create an extension that looks for a specific wording in the speaker notes inside "punch-viewer-speakernotes-text-body-scrollable" and if found then display something on the page.

[image]

In dev tools I can see that presenter view has a start URL "/presentation/?usp=installed_webapp" and App Id "https://docs.google.com/presentation/?usp=installed_webapp", I tried both in "matches" but didn't work. I have a feeling that I need to use `"matches": ["https://docs.google.com/presentation/*"]` and use JS triggering only based on DIV name present.

Comment: I think it's impossible because DevTools doesn't open there.

Comment: No it does open, sorry I should have pointed out that on Mac you need to put the browser first into full screen window and then start presenter view, that way the presenter view opens in a new tab "about:blank" and dev tools open. Can you pls check again?

Comment: I found a partial solution using "match_about_blank" flag but not sure how I can target the extension to only apply to the about page rather than all other pages too from same domain, maybe you know how I could limit it or use JS? I've updated the post, Thanks @NorioYamamoto